# Vertical and Horizontal alignment of text issue with Select Box in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

Please help me to resolve this vertical and horizontal aligning of text  issue in select box with Internet Explorer 8. Text in select box is aligning at bottom instead of aligning at the middle.

Here is the problem snapshot :
[image]
Doctype Declaration tag used is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->
```

HTml Code is :

```html
<div class="search">
   <span class="search-btn">
    <span class="open">
     <i class="ico ico-zoom"></i>
     Search
    </span>
   
    <span class="close hidden">
     <i class="ico ico-x"></i>
     Close
    </span>
   </span>
   <div class="form-body hidden">
   
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-date" class="form-label">Date</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">      
      <input type="text" class="field field-small" placeholder="From" id="field-date" name="<%=DateSearchControllerHelper.DATE_FROM%>" readonly="readonly" value="${dateFrom}" <c:if test="${!empty requestScope.dateFromInvalid}">class="red"</c:if>>  
      <label for="field-date">
       <i class="ico ico-calendar"></i>
      </label>           
      <input type="text"  class="field field-small" placeholder="To" id="field-date2" name="<%=DateSearchControllerHelper.DATE_TO%>" readonly="readonly" value="${dateTo}" <c:if test="${!empty requestScope.dateToInvalid}">class="red"</c:if>>    
      <label for="field-date2">
       <i class="ico ico-calendar"></i>
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
      </div><!-- /.form-row -->
<input type="hidden" name="submitDateSearch" id="submitDateSearch"  value="true"/>
<div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-select" class="form-label">Select Column</label>     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">
       <select id="colList1" name="colList1" class="select">
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${colList1}">
         <option value="${column}" <c:if test="${column == colListSelection1}">SELECTED</c:if>>${column}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>       
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->       
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <input type="text" class="field" name="value1" id="value1" value="${value1}" onKeyPress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnSearch(event,this.form,this)">      
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria" class="form-label">&nbsp;</label>
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">
       <select name="andOr" id="andOr" class="select select-small">
        <option value="and" <c:if test="${andOr == 'and'}">SELECTED</c:if>>and</option>
        <option value="or" <c:if test="${andOr == 'or'}">SELECTED</c:if>>or</option>
       </select>       
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-column2" class="form-label">Select Column</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <label class="select-label">
       <select name="colList2" id="colList2" class="select">
        <c:forEach var="column" items="${colList2}">
         <option value="${column}" <c:if test="${column == colListSelection2}">SELECTED</c:if>>${column}</option>
        </c:forEach>
       </select>
      </label>
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-row">
     <label for="field-criteria2" class="form-label">Search Criteria</label>
     
     <div class="form-controls">
      <input type="text" class="field" name="value2" id="value2" value="${value2}" onKeyPress="javascript:validateEnterKeyOnSearch(event, this.form, this)">           
     </div><!-- /.form-controls -->
    </div><!-- /.form-row -->
          
    <div class="form-actions">    
     <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:performSearch(this.form.name,<%=AppProperties.ROWS_PER_PAGE%>,<%=AppProperties.ELCY_LIST_MAX_SIZE%>);" class="btn btn-green" />
    </div><!-- /.form-actions -->
   </div><!-- /.form-body -->
 <input type="hidden" name="submitSearch" id="submitSearch" value="true"/>
```

Css Code used is :

```css
.search { float: left; margin-left: 4px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-family: "Arial Black","Arial Bold",Gadget,sans-serif; }
.search-btn { display: inline-block; width: 90px; height: 28px; margin: 21px 0 0 4px; background-color: #55be28; font-size: 11px; line-height: 28px; text-align: center; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.search-btn { 
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
         transition: opacity 0.4s;
 }
.search-btn:hover { opacity: .7; }
.search-btn .ico { margin-right: 5px; }

.form-body,
.form-row { display: inline-block; }

.form-body.hidden { opacity: 0; }
.form-body { opacity: 1; }
.form-body { 
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s;
         transition: opacity 1s;
 }

.form-row { margin-left: 10px; float:left; }
.form-label { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size: 10px; line-height: 13px; color: #464646; }
.field,
.select { width: 88px; height: 28px; padding: 0 10px; border: 1px solid  #e1e1e1; font-size: 11px; line-height: 28px; color: #464646; }
.field-small { width: 65px; }
.select { width: auto; height: 30px; padding:0;}
.select-small { width: 70px; }

.form-controls label + input { margin-left: 20px; } 
.form-controls label .ico { margin: -17px 0 0 5px; vertical-align: top; cursor: pointer; }
.form-controls label { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.form-controls .select-label:after { display:none;/*content: ''; position: absolute; top: 1px; right: 1px; width: 29px; height: 28px; background: url(images/sprite.png) -124px -27px no-repeat; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: none;*/ }

.form-actions { overflow: hidden; /*padding-top: 5px; by me*/  display: inline; }
.form-actions .btn { float: right; /*Extra from me*/ margin:21px 0 0 10px; }
.hidden { display: none; visibility: hidden; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Besides the fact, that i'm wondering, why there is a different doctype for <IE8 in the first place, even if it would work (which I'm really not sure about), this should not affect IE8 itself, because it says `lt` and not `lte` which would include IE8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with the Doctype suggested with lte, but it also did not worked.